# How to get the flyway bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway, applicationcontext

There is a class in Spring boot sources which loads flyway configuration https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration.java

Check the following code:

```
    @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "flyway")
    public Flyway flyway() {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        if (this.properties.isCreateDataSource()) {
            flyway.setDataSource(this.properties.getUrl(), this.properties.getUser(),
                    this.properties.getPassword(), this.properties.getInitSqls()
                            .toArray(new String[0]));
        }
        else if (this.flywayDataSource != null) {
            flyway.setDataSource(this.flywayDataSource);
        }
        else {
            flyway.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        }
        return flyway;
    }
```

I need the instance of `Flyway` class. My code:

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    Flyway flyway = ctx.getBean(Flyway.class);
```

fails with:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
at co.ambisafe.keyserver.Application.main(Application.java:14)
... 6 more
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Is your `Application` class annotated with `EnableAutoConfiguration` or `SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: Why do you need the bean? The migration already ran when you obtain it.

Comment: First check that the flyway bean is created at all. - For example by setting an breakpoint in the flyway bean post construct method. -- It is because I guess that one of the conditions is not fullfilled https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration.java

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, Yes.

Comment: @Ralph, My bean is created. Because my migrations were running during the start. Now I disabled it.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I need this bean to run flyway api functional like validate, repair and other stuff

Comment: The next thing I'd check is that Boot's Flyway auto-configuration is actually running. Try starting your app with `--debug` and take a look at the auto-configuration report that it produces to see where `FlywayAutoConfiguration` is mentioned. Maybe also take a look at Boot's [Flyway sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-flyway). I just tried modifying it to retrieve the Flyway bean and it worked as expected.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, I found the issue. I added to my application.yml
flyway:
      enabled: false
I thought it only disables the migrations on start. I was wrong. It disables the bean.

Comment: And how did you disable the migrations then?